# Click outside directive with ngIf?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

I use the following directive to detect and hide block if click was outside concrete DOM element:

```
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  HostListener
} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[clickOutside]"
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  @Output()
  public clickOutside = new EventEmitter();

  @HostListener("document:click", ["$event.target"])
  public onClick(targetElement) {
    const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(
      targetElement
    );

    this.clickOutside.emit(clickedInside);
  }
}
```

I have applied this directive **to element:**

```
<div class="action" (click)="open()">Open</div>
<div
    class="search_content"
    *ngIf="_searchContentOpen"
    clickOutside
    (clickOutside)="clickOutside($event)"
  ></div>
```

**Component code is:**

```
open(): void {
   this._searchContentOpen = !this._searchContentOpen;
}
```

Problem is when I call click I set `this._searchContentOpen` to true/false.

Depends it I show block where directive applied. But directive works always also in step when ngIf works. So as result block never is showen.

How to fix it?

Comment: To click outside without listening to document click, you need to create a backdrop

Comment: I sort of understand the code and what you're trying to do, but I'm not sure what the problem is.  Can you expand on the question?

Comment: @Ferhado He is listening for a click on document in the `@HostListener` that is part of the directive code.

Comment: The clickOutside handler checks if target element is in the list but in your case it is not, because it was removed from DOM by *ngIf directive. Stop propagation in that case helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are my two options:

1) using `event.stopPropagation()` on trigger

```
<div class="action" (click)="open(); $event.stopPropagation()">Open</div>
```

2) handle click only after directive is applied

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective implements OnInit {
  @Output() clickOutside = new EventEmitter();

  captured = false;

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
  onClick(target) {
    if (!this.captured) {
      return;
    }

    if (!this.elRef.nativeElement.contains(target)) {
      this.clickOutside.emit();
    };
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    fromEvent(document, 'click', { capture: true }).pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(() => this.captured = true);

    /* or
    document.addEventListener('click', () => this.captured = true, { 
      capture: true,
      once: true
    });
    */
  }
}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/ybBD5ohH6l0CQ24Rp5b2?open=app%2Fclickoutside.directive.ts&layout=1)**